# Moving netbeans and PHP from Win to Ubuntu - what directory structure?

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans, ubuntu

I have been learning PHP and Zend FW on Win32.  In the last few days I setup Ubuntu and am cutting over all my stuff.

On Win32, I had a single parent directory for my netbeans projects.  I did both dev and testing there.  (I don't have any production apps as yet.)

Anyhow, on Ubuntu, netbeans wants to store projects in /home/username.  This is not beneath my web root though, so AFAICS, I won't be able to code and test without a deployment in between.

How do other netbeans/linux users go about handling this?  Do you develop in /home/username, then deploy to /var/www/myapp/test to run it in a browser?  Or do both your dev and test directories live under the web root?  Or do you symlink out of the web root?  Or ...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is your development machine, you can control your web root, so simply setup a vhost for each project to point at `/home/username/netbeans/projectname/public` (or whatever Netbeans uses).